# Does the DocumentTranslator app support Azure china translation services?

Tags: microsoft-translator

DocumentTranslator 这个APP是否支持 中国区的Azure翻译服务

```
ERROR Unauthorized
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401000,
    "message": "The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not contain a correct authentication method in the request header